# How can I create a static node on the jstree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

```
$("#orgTree").jstree({
    json_data: {
        ajax:{url: ctx+"/account/org-tree.action"}
    }
});
$("#orgTree").jstree("create_node",null,"first",{attr:{id:100},data:"test"});
```

I want create a default superNode on the tree,but the code:

```
$('#orgTree').jstree("create_node", null, "first", {attr : {id: 100}, data: "test"});
```

not working,Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way I resolved it was by attaching to the `loaded` event on the tree to only insert the supernode *after* the rest of the tree was created. Also, rather than passing in `null` I just passed in the first node in the tree. In your case, it would look like:

```
var $tree = $("#orgTree");
$tree.jstree({
    json_data: {
        ajax:{url: ctx+"/account/org-tree.action"}
    }
});

$tree.on("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) {
    var supernode = {attr : {id: 100}, data: "test"};

    $tree.jstree("create_node", $("li:first", $tree), "before", supernode );
});
```

Note that I'm using `on` as I'm using jQuery 1.7